# protobuf-net Guid deserializing to Guid.Empty when using inheritance

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm having issues deserializing a Guid when the Guid is defined in a message base class. When I have the following message.

```
 [DataContract]
public abstract class GatewayPageEvent:IDomainEvent
{
    protected GatewayPageEvent()
    {
        On = DateTime.Now;
    }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)] public Guid GatewayPageId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)] public DateTime On { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class GatewayPageAddedToSite : GatewayPageEvent
{
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]public string Url { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]public string SiteCode { get; set; }
}
```

GatewayPageId is always deserializing as Guid.Empty. Here's a unit test I wrote that fails. I'm kinda stumped...

```
    public string Serialize(object t)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, t);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }

    public object Deserialize(string value, Type targetType)
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        return ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(targetType, stream);
    }
    [Test]
    public void protobuf_serialization_can_deserialized_guids()
    {
        var originalMessage = new GatewayPageAddedToSite
                                  {GatewayPageId = Guid.NewGuid(), SiteCode = "dls", Url = "test"};
        var serializedMessage = Serialize(originalMessage);
        var @event = (GatewayPageAddedToSite)Deserialize(serializedMessage, typeof(GatewayPageAddedToSite));
        Assert.AreEqual(@event.GatewayPageId, originalMessage.GatewayPageId);
    }
```

I know Guids work fine because the following unit test works just fine.

```
[Test]
    public void guids_work_fine()
    {
        var original = Guid.NewGuid();
        var serialized = Serialize(original);
        var deserialized = (Guid) Deserialize(serialized, typeof (Guid));
        Assert.AreEqual(original,deserialized);
    }
```

Am I defining my contract wrong? Or is this a problem with protobuf-net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With protobuf-net, it needs to know about inheritance ahead of time (actually, so does `DataContractSerializer`, usually - via `[KnownType(...)]`). In the case of protobuf-net, it also needs a unique key to distinguish them, something like:

```
[DataContract, ProtoInclude(3, typeof(GatewayPageAddedToSite))]
public abstract class GatewayPageEvent:IDomainEvent
{...}
[DataContract]
public class GatewayPageAddedToSite : GatewayPageEvent
{...}
```

(i.e. the base-type needs to be told about the derived types)

Note that the numbers only need to be unique *within each type*, so there is no collision between the "3" in the include vs the "3" in `GatewayPageAddedToSite` - and actually, `GatewayPageAddedToSite` could use "1" and "2" if it wants.

If your domain model is generated, then a separate partial class file might help:

```
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(GatewayPageAddedToSite)]
partial class GatewayPageEvent {}
```

If you really don't want to upset your model with these things, then in v2 you can do this at runtime instead:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(GatewayPageEvent)]
      .AddSubType(3, typeof(GatewayPageAddedToSite));
```

any of that make it work?

Comment: Trying that now, but if that's the case, wouldn't an

Assert.AreEqual(originalMessage.On.Date, @event.On.Date);

Would fail, but it doesn't.

Comment: Added if (targetType.BaseType != typeof(object))
            {
                RuntimeTypeModel.Default[targetType.BaseType].AddSubType(100, targetType);
            }

to my serialize method, and test passes... Thanks man!

Comment: @Elliot note that the numbers are part of the data; make sure you can reproduce the right numbers (for different sub-types of the same base-type, etc)